# Android MainActivity to pass intent to another activity

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am having problem in trying to call another class called `FetchData` which in turn contains the `AsyncTask` Method .

My Main Activity code is:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";

    private Button btn;
    private EditText edit;
    private Spinner spinner;
    //private TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        //textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        btn.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(View view)
                    {
                        //Log.v("EditText", edit.getText().toString());
                       // Log.v("Spinner", spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
                        //if(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString()=="All Types")
                         String[] customarr = {"feature,tv_series,game","feature","tv_series","game"};
                         String selecteditem = customarr[spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()];

                        String url="http://cs-server.usc.edu:23405/examples/servlet/HelloWorldExample?title="+edit.getText().toString()+"&type="+selecteditem;
                        Log.v("url",url);


                        Intent intent=new Intent(this,FetchData.class);
                        String message=url;
                        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });



    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.title_type,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    //String url="http://cs-server.usc.edu:23405/examples/servlet/HelloWorldExample?title="+edit.getText().toString()+"&type="+spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
     // Log.v("url",url);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
            //Object item = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);

        }
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });


    }
}
```

I am having the error

```
The constructor Intent(new View.OnClickListener(){}, Class<FetchData>) is undefined
```

Any ideas.? I think i am doing a silly mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the line `Intent intent=new Intent(this,FetchData.class);` replace `this` with `MainActivity.this`, as `this` alone refere to the `onClickListener`

```
Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,FetchData.class);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `MainActivity.this` in the constructor. This is because you are inside a `OnClickListener` and `this` refers to it.

Answer (score 2):

Intent constructor need activity context as its first parameter and `this` in `onClickListener()` refer to the object of the click listener class. To access the instance reference of the `class` in the `inner class` use `NameOfTheClass.this`, in your case it should be `MainActivity.this`

Change the following line in your code

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this,FetchData.class);
```

to

```
Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,FetchData.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

ested provided within an event must do the following

**youActivity.this**

if not, if only for **this**, will be making reference to the object that is currently

I recommend that if you do this outside OnCreate

Intent intent = new Intent(YouActivyti.this,otheractivity.class)

if found within OnCreate

Intent intent = new Intent(this,otheractivity.class)

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,FetchData.class);
```

You forgot to mention the MainActivity

Answer (score -1):

->you are inside a oncreate method and using onClickListener interface so inside onCLick method if u only use-
 Intent intent = new Intent(this,classname.class);
then in that case (this) refers to the onClickListener interface but you want to use your current class instance so thats why u have to mention.

this line of code

> ***Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,FetchData.class);**

Hope This Help!!